# Can constant and time-dependent features be mixed?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Suppose I'm trying to perform supervised classification on a list of birds into either nocturnal or diurnal. The only features I have regarding each bird are

- its wingspan (float),
- its colour (multi-class: white, brown, red, yellow, blue, green, black),
- its diet (binary: carnivore or not),
- its habitat (multi-class: ocean, river, mountain, desert), and
- a sound recording of their call/song (time series of floats)

Let's say I want to use a neural network. A feed-forward neural network will work just fine for the first four features. (The wingspan  will simply be one of the nodes in the input layer whereas colour, diet, and habitat will be decomposed into several input nodes, presumably via one-hot encoding.)

However, how shall one deal with the last feature, namely the recording of the bird sounds? If this were the only feature, the natural choice would be a recurrent neural network (RNN), but then what should one do with the first four constant features? Clearly, copying them at each recursion of the RNN is both redundant and contrary to the "spirit" of RNNs since, for example, the colour of the bird isn't expected to change from one sound bit to the next.

In other words, how does the architecture of the neural net account for such mixed features? (The same question applies to other classifiers such as support vector machines.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use RNNs, just modify the architecture a bit: plug the time series into a few layers of LSTMs or whatever you'd like to use, and then concatenate the resulting hidden states and the discrete features you have into a softmax layer that produces predictions. So, your computational graph would look like this: [image]

Alternatively, there is no rule saying you can't include those constant features as input to the RNN.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what your diagram from the Keras documentation illustrates. 

Let me get this straight: You're saying I should first train the RNN on the time series using a sequence to sequence model and then feed the output sequence along with the first four features into a feed-forward neural network (FFNN)? So essentially, I'd train twice in a supervised fashion, first on the time series using an RNN and then on the output of the RNN along with the first four features in a FFNN?

Comment: No, you train once. Your output is the bird class, right? so the gradient flows back to the merge layer, and there it flows into the two input columns. So, for this schema, you'd split your training data in two: the sounds and the discrete features, and instead of calling `fit(X_train, y_train)` you'd say something like `fit([X_train_discrete, X_train_songs], y_train)`

Comment: Oh yeah, and you probably don't want an embedding layer there.

Comment: Alright, so you're saying the RNN will take as inputs the songs and then output a fixed-length vector which will then be concatenated with the first four features as the input to the feedforward neural network?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Note that X_train_songs might be a 3-dimensional tensor or a matrix depending on your data, while X_train_discrete will be a matrix.

Comment: But then there remains the question of choosing the length of the output sequence from the RNN... Plus assembling this hybrid thing on TensorFlow is no piece of cake.

Comment: The output of the LSTM need not be a sequence. You can just output the hidden states in the end of the recording.

Comment: The problem with just using the hidden states is that the input sequences can be of varying lengths whereas the FFNN expects fixed-length input layers. That's why it's better to use a fixed-length output sequence to act as an embedding of sorts.

Comment: I think you are confusing the hidden vector length and the input sequence length. While the input sequence can be of varying length, the hidden vector will always have the same dimension.

Comment: Right---But then it'll have to be the final state of the hidden layer. I see.